# Remove Duplicates from ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Object

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList that has a nested ArrayList of Strings and I want to remove duplicates from.  I know if I always wanted to remove duplicates, I shouldn't use an ArrayList, but in some cases duplicates are valid.  What is the best way to remove duplicates from the nested ArrayList?

**For example, I would like to execute some Java that converts:**

```
[[duplicate], [duplicate], [duplicate], [unique1], [unique2]]
```

**to:**

```
[[duplicate], [unique1], [unique2]]
```

Comment: Isnt making a new HashSet<Object>(List<Object> ... ) the answer? Then convert to List again

Comment: You say that it's a list of lists. Do you want `{ {1, 2}, {1, 3} }` to be collapsed to `{ { 1, 2 }, { 3 } }`? or should each inner list be treated in isolation?

Comment: I am a bit confused too.  Are you looking for [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3], [1,2]] to become [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3]], or [1, 2, 3] or what aioobe said?

Comment: @Itfishie - [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3], [1,2]] to become become [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3]]

Comment: @Itfishie - sorry misunderstood i want it to become [1,2,3], your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What aioobe said, using a set, except you will put it in a loop since you have a two demisional array:

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (ArrayList<String> list:yourList) {
    set.addAll (list);
}
ArrayList<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Answer (score 11):

To remove duplicates from an ArrayList you could do

```
yourList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(yourList));
```

Using `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet` ensures that the order of the original lists are preserved.

---

Regarding your comment:

Here's a solution that transforms `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [3], [1,2]]` to `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [3]]`.

```
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();
for (List<String> l : strLists) {
    for (Iterator<String> iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        if (!seen.add(iter.next()))
            iter.remove();

    // If you want to remove lists that end up empty:
    if (l.isEmpty())
        strLists.remove(l);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RunDuplicate
{
public RunDuplicate()
{
super();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
String[] duplicates = new String[] {"duplicate","duplicate","duplicate","unique1","unique2"};

Arrays.sort(duplicates);

int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < duplicates.length; i++)
{
if (i > 0 && duplicates[i].equals(duplicates[i -1]))
continue;

duplicates[k++] = duplicates[i];
}

String[] unique = new String[k];

System.arraycopy(duplicates, 0, unique, 0, k);

//test that unique contains no duplicate strings
for (int i = 0; i < unique.length; i++)
System.out.println(unique[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
for (Iterator<ArrayList<String>> it = myListInList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{ 
   ArrayList<String> current = it.next();
   HashSet h = new HashSet(current);
   current.clear();
   current.addAll(h);
}
```

Comment: -1 for using iterator (instead of a for-each loop) and raw HashSet (which also doesn't preserve ordering of the original list)

Comment: I think using iterator pattern is useful. Hashset will cause that the ordering will be corrupt but it was irrelevant in this case [i can't see it as prerequisite].